# R predict func type="class" error

Tags: r, classification, prediction, predict

I'm working with a data set to try to be able to fit a classification tree
I split the data set:

```
set.seed(2)
train=sample(1:nrow(mydata),nrow(mydata)/2)
test=-train
training_data=mydata[train,]
testing_data=mydata[test,]
testing_Donates=Donates[test]
```

After doing that I made a tree model:

```
tree_model=tree(Donates~.,training_data)
plot(tree_model)
text(tree_model)
```

Then I tried using the predict function:

```
tree_pred<- predict(tree_model, testing_data, type="class")
```

but I keep receiving an error :

> Error in predict.tree(tree_model, testing_data, type = "class") :
>       type "class" only for classification trees

can someone tell me what is wrong and how I could fix this?

Comment: Where does `tree` come from?

Comment: from the library(tree) package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same issue today and this post is all I could find. Turns out R automatically views integers as interval variables, even though you might sometimes want to view them as categorical values. You can force this by using

```
as.factor(x)
```

on the list of categorical integer values. So when creating the model use:

```
tree_model=tree(as.factor(Donates)~.,training_data)
```

Comment: Thank you! It definitely was an issue with the dependent value not being a categorical value.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could also used "vector" and it will work perfectly.

If you are working with a regression tree, you should use type = "vector" instead of type = "class" when calling the predict() function.

Hope it help ...